# Why I cannot render pug variable through node

Tags: pug

I want to ask a simple question about pug:

```
html  
    head
        title This is my first Pug file
    body
        header
            p= paragaph
        section
            p gdghdhgdhdhdh
        footer
            cool footer with lots of copyrights.
route.get('/Artists/test',(req,res)=> {
    res.render('test.pug', {paragraph: 'Hi there'});
})
```

I do not know why the "p" just did not show up on the browser, but the rest of the element is okay

sort of confused by what is happening here.

Answer (score 1):

Look closely at how you are calling the template:

```
res.render('test.pug', {paragraph: 'Hi there'});
                        ^^^^^^^^^
```

Then look closely at how you are calling the variable:

```
p= paragaph
   ^^^^^^^^
```

`paragaph` does not match `paragraph` and pug will not render an empty div.